# Nothing output while using 'xlsxwriter' to write in Excel

Tags: python, excel, xlsxwriter

I use the following code to write data to an excel file, but got nothing in the excel file. How can I get my desired output:

Code:

```
import xlsxwriter
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('print_def.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
tree = 'YES'
while i < 4:
    worksheet.write(i, 0,  tree) #nothing is written to the excel file
    i+=1
workbook.close()
```

My desired output:

```
1  YES
2  YES
3  YES
4  YES
```

**Question**: How can I update the code for my desired output? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the default value of `i`? If you add `i=0` before `while i < 4`, this code should work?

Comment: Oh yes, thanks a lot, I forgot to give an initial value to `i`, it should be `i=0`. And it works now after adding `i=0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed by @Lucvv, I forgot to put `i=0` in the code, it then works after adding `i=0`.